# How to combine 2 partially sorted arrays?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, sorting, data-structures

Given 2 arrays with int, A1 and A2. A1 length is L1, A2 length is L1+L2. 
The first L2 elements of A1 and A2 have been sorted. Combine the first L2 elements into A2. 
e.g.

```
   A1:  1  3  6  0
   A2:  2  5  7  13  10 22 11 
   result: 
   A1 + A2:  1 2 3 5 6 7 13 10 22  11
```

my solutions:

Pick each element by putting min { A1[i], A2[i]}  into a array B[i], O(2 * L2)
Copy B to A2. O(L1 + L2).

Unsorted part should not be changed.

Any better solutions ?

thanks

Comment: Well, I've tried a few ideas, but none of them take into account the nearly sorted-ness of your values.  My gut tells me you should be able to get slightly better, but not much.  Even bucket sort throws away most of the advantage of your pre-sort.  Still thinking about it though...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm

Comment: By "Combine the first L2 elements into A2", do you mean "the first L1+L2 elements"? It would seem so, since you define the A2.length as L1+L2, and L2 would be an important number to keep, since you want to keep the last L2 numbers and append them.

Comment: A2 size will be L2 +L2 + L1  (sorted + unsorted)

Comment: What's with the trailing 0 at the end of A1?

Comment: That element, apparently, gets excluded from the result, @Mooing. In the example here, L1 = 4 and L2 = 3. The first L2 elements of A1 and A2 are sorted (but coincidentally, the next element of A2 happens to be in the right order relative to the previous entries).

Comment: Yeah, I don't really get why the algorithm calls for the last element of A1 to get culled, but not the corresponding element in A2... @user1002288 may want to confirm that... at any rate, I've edited my answer to reflect that behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int* semiMerge(int*, int, int*, int);

int main() {
  const int A1[] = {1, 3, 6, 0};
  const int A2[] = {2, 5, 7, 13, 10, 22, 11};

  const int L1 = sizeof(A1)/sizeof(int);
  const int L2 = sizeof(A2)/sizeof(int) - L1;

  int* out = semiMerge(A1, L1, A2, L2);
}

int* semiMerge(A1, L1, A2, L2) {
  int* output = new int[L2 + L2 + L1];

  //merge does a sorted combination of the items--both sets must be sorted up to the endpoints;
  //we want to merge only the first L1 results from each array
  std::merge(A1, A1 + L2,
             A2, A2 + L2,
             output);
  //at this point, we have an array of 2*L1 elements, all sorted properly.


  //we want to start looking at the first element we didn't copy from A2,
  //the -1 is to account for the fact that begin() + L1 is the start of the L1+1th slot
  std::copy(A2 + L2,
            A2 + L2 + L1, 
            (output + L2 + L2 - 1));

return output;
}
```

I chose to show A1 and A1 as static arrays, but if you're getting them as `int*`s to heap-allocated arrays, and if it's important that the finished array be placed in L2, you can then say `delete[] L2; L2 = out;` after the call to `semiMerge()`. I chose not to do this in main because I represented `A2` as a static array, while switching it out for the contents of `out` would require it to be a pointer to a dynamic array.

Comment: Completed your method and made sure no memory is leaked.

Comment: @AndréCaron uh, maybe I'm missing something, but the only change I see is that you changed output to a `std::vector<int>`, which, because you didn't change the type of the variable it's stored in, just breaks the code... It was valid to act directly on a dynamic int array, as long as the client remembers to call `delete[]`.

Comment: @mathias: It's the other way around.  I changed the type of the `output` variable, not the return type of the function.  Your previous example was invalid since (1) it attempted to construct a vector from a single `int*` argument and (2) it always leaked the allocated memory since the only pointer to it was in a local variable.

Comment: @mathias: I didn't notice that the function forward declaration and `main()` were expecting `int*` as output though.  Nice catch!

Comment: Yeah, I had originally implemented it in terms of vector, but decided to lower it to `int*` because the OP is talking about dealing with arrays. You caught the one part I missed and did the inverse of what I should have done. Also, you do return the pointer to the array, and it's the client's responsibility to manage it at that point. I did use the wrong `delete` in the bottom paragraph though; I've changed that.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I've figured out what `L1` and `L2` are:

```
{
    std::vector<int> B(L2+L2+L1, 0);
    std::merge(A1.begin(), A1.begin()+L2, A2.begin(), A2.begin()+L2, B.begin());
    if (L1 > L2)
        B.insert(B.end(), A2.begin()+L2, A2.end());
    A2.swap(B);
}
```

B contains [merged sorted part][unsorted A2].  Is that the correct format?  This is the algorithm you posted.  In place (like Nim) is slower, but uses less memory, so it's a trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy A1 and A2 into one array
2. std::inplace_merge with begin, begin + L2, end

(well you didn't specify no library functions!) ;)

This sounds like a homework problem, and I normally hesitate before providing code for homework. However it looks like an example is required here:

```
std::vector<int> A1; // initialize to { 1  3  6  0 }
std::vector<int> A2; // initialize to { 2  5  7  13  10 22 11 }

// Now assumption here is that we want L2 items from A1, so let's copy
A2.insert(A2.begin(), A1.begin(), A1.begin() + L2);

// Now A2 contains the sorted range from A1 0 is dropped (?)
// Now call inplace_merge, this leaves the unsorted segment of A2 alone, and only includes
// L2 items from A2.
std::inplace_merge(A2.begin(), A2.begin() + L2, A2.begin() + (2*L2));
```

Comment: it is (2 * L2 * lg 2*L2). when L2 >> L1, it is not efficient.

Comment: what's wrong with `merge(begin(A1), end(A1), begin(A2), end(A2), back_inserter(dest));`?

Comment: @mooing, yes if B can be a separate array, if A2 (or A1) is enough for both the inplace is better I guess...

Comment: A2 is only partially sorted. The unsorted part should not be changed.

Comment: In that case inplace is deffinitely better, end would be the end of the two sorted ranges. That would leave the unsorted segment alone. I would double check the NlogN claim...

Comment: @user, this is an adaptive algorithm, meaning that best case can actually be linear, worst is NLogN

Comment: Part of A2 is sorted and another part is not, and they should remain in this state. Why these parts aren't kept in different arrays? This would simplify everything and provide O(2* L2).

Comment: @user1002288: I failed to notice the unsorted part, sorry

Comment: I don't think you can count on `inplace_merge` doing what you'd hope here - http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/inplace_merge.html - The preconditions are that the ranges are in ascending order, which these two ranges are not.

Comment: n3290, § 25.4.4/7 *"Requires: The ranges [first,middle) and [middle,last) shall be sorted with respect to operator<
or comp"*

Comment: @awoodland, hmm, not sure about that, I believe the OP wants part of A1 and part of A2, looks like the unwanted part of A1 is not included in the final which contains the sorted range in A1 and all of A2. inplace would be perfect for this. First step, copy the sorted range of A1 into the start of A2 (having shifted that), then the input to inplace_merge would be begin, begin + L2, and begin + 2L2. This leaves the unsorted range in A2 in place. For such a small array, the likely hood is that the internal buffer will be enough, and hence linear in time,